# Commit all is greyed out in Team Explorer in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

I created a project CmsShoppingCart in vs 2015 and created a local repository. But when I want to add commit for the first time, I found the Commit All button is greyed out all showed in the pictures below. Is any suggestion to such an issue? Thank you very much. Also, this is the first time I am using Team Explorer.

[Setting for local repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHx0e.jpg)

[Commit All button greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF23D.jpg)

Comment: what do you see when you click on the "Actions" dropdown menu?

Comment: It showed Open In File Explorer; Open Command Prompt; View History...Others are greyed out. 
In fact I found the problem already, I need to make a change on project files before the commit button works. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Amy, what was the problem and what change did you have to make?

Comment: March 2023 - I ran to into issue and tried few answers given below, but it didn't work. I restarted VS and the commit button was enabled again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found in my situation that I need to make a change on the project files before the commit button works.

Comment: I will accept it tomorrow for it shows "You can accept your own answer tomorrow".

Answer (score 29):

In my case (Visual Studio 2022) it was all I needed to correct my email address in menu > Git > Settings > Git Repository Settings > Email same as in menu > Settings > Git Global Settings and the problem was resolved.

[image]

Comment: You have to restart Visual Studio after fix.

Comment: It also had the incorrect default location value. Setting it to the right project folder resolved for me (after restarting VS).

Answer (score 14):

In my case i had to run
Run

`git config --global user.email "me@example.com"` and
`git config --global user.name "My Name"`

Comment: I logged in just to upvote. This worked for me, despite the fact that looking at all of the settings in VS 2022 showed the correct values. I ran these git commands, closed and re-opened VS and Commit was re-enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the same happened in the Git window in Visual Studio 2022.
I was logged in to Visual Studio with a different account than the Git repository. I solved it by changing the email in the global Git settings to the email for the Git account without signing in with that email in Visual Studio. If that doesn't work, you can try signing in to Visual Studio with the email account associated with the Git repository.